# Local cohomology with coefficients in ideals of parameters

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, d-modules, local-cohomology

I'm not an expert in local cohomology, but the following problems have come up in my work, and I'd like to get a sense of where things stand.

Let $\mathbb{A}^n=\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots x_n]$ be affine space. Let $I$ be an ideal given by $(x_1, \dots x_k)$ for some $0 \leq k \leq n$, and let $M$ be a similar ideal, with generators $(x_{i_1}, \dots x_{i_j})$. The first problem: compute the local cohomology spaces $H^i_{I}(\mathbb{A}^n, M)$.

Just from poking around with Cech complexes, this seems pretty straightforward and combinatorial. In particular:

$H^0_{I}(\mathbb{A}^n, M)=0$ when $I$ is not 0, since the generators (in any order) of $I$ form a regular sequence on $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots x_n]$ and a fortiriori no elements of $M \subset \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots x_n]$ can be $I-$torsion.

$H^1_{I}(\mathbb{A}^n, M)= 0$ if $I \not\subset M$. If $I \subset M$, then
$H^1_{I}(\mathbb{A}^n,M)$ should be "cyclic" (in the D-module sense), with generator given by Cech cocycle $(\frac{x_1}{x_1}, \dots \frac{x_k}{x_k}) \in \bigoplus_{i} M_{(x_i)}$.

More generally, the higher terms seem to be given by some kind of inclusion/exclusion. Example: a Cech cocycle in $Z^2_{(x_1, x_2, x_3,x_4)}(\mathbb{A}^5, (x_2, x_3,x_4,x_5))$ is $(\frac{x_2}{x_1x_2},\frac{x_3}{x_1x_3}, \frac{-x_4}{x_1x_4},\frac{0}{x_2x_3}, \frac{0}{x_2x_4},\frac{0}{x_3x_4})$.

Do all generators (again in a D-module sense) appear in this combinatorial fashion? Do concrete descriptions of these generators appear in the literature?

Lastly, if this is all well known, does it generalize to the setup where $X$ is a reduced Cohen-Macaulay scheme, with $I$ and $M$ both being ideals generated by (subsets of) systems of parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure I believe in general that $H_I^1(\mathbb{A}^n, M) = 0$ if $I \not\subseteq M$.  If $I$ happens to be principal say $I = (x_1)$, then that local cohomology should be nonzero no matter what.  I expect that questions in this direction (D-module generators in this particularly combinatorial / toric setting) are well known but I don't know the literature well enough to point out things off the top of my head.  You may want to look at this paper by Lyubeznik:  https://eudml.org/doc/144121  As well as the papers that cite it.  It might lead you two someone who has done this before.

Comment: You're certainly right about H^1 being nontrivial if I is principal; I forgot to mention that. However I'm really interested about the 'internal structure' so to speak: the cohomology H^i when i is less than the number of generators. Thank you for your reference though!